# Get Topic ARN from aws using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can someone please let me know how to get the exact topic arn from SNS using AmazonSNSClient in java ?

I want to use it in the following PutMetricAlarmRequest

```
.withAlarmActions(awsClient.getAmazonSNSClient(). ?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get a list of all SNS topics. You can call `Topic::getTopicArn()` to get the ARN as a String.

```
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

    List<Topic> topicArns = new ArrayList<>();

    ListTopicsResult result = snsClient.listTopics();
    topicArns.addAll(result.getTopics());

    while (result.getNextToken() != null) {
        result = snsClient.listTopics(result.getNextToken());
        topicArns.addAll(result.getTopics());
    }

    for (Topic topic : topicArns) {
        System.out.println(topic.getTopicArn());
    }

    snsClient.shutdown();
```

Change the credentials provider and region to match your account, and make sure you have the appropriate permissions set in IAM for your user.